# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error when using JSON with PHP 5.6

Tags: php, json

I have PHP web page, but I have one problem with the code, I search here, got some similar answer, but sorry I do not understand how to fix my error. When I use MySQLI and PHP 7.1, then my web page work but there is some error, when I use MySQL and PHP 5.6, then my web page works perfect, except for this error, which is below.

this is my error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: ' in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php:95 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php(53): BlockIo->_request('get_new_address', Array) #1 /var/www/html/block.php(20): BlockIo->__call('get_new_address', Array) #2 /var/www/html/block.php(20): BlockIo->get_new_address() #3 /var/www/html/deposit.php(76): include('/var/www/html/b...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95
```

this is a lines from the code

```
81         // it's a GET method
82         if ($method == 'GET') { $url .= '&' . $addedData; }
83         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
84         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
85         if ($method == 'POST')
86         { // this was a POST method
87         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
88         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $addedData);
89         }
90         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
91         // Execute the cURL request
92         $result = curl_exec($ch);
93         curl_close($ch);
94         $json_result = json_decode($result);
95         if ($json_result->status != 'success') { throw new 
           Exception('Failed: ' . $json_result->data->error_message); }
96          // Spit back the response object or fail
97          return $result ? $json_result : false;        
98          }
```

I know that I can't ask good question, I don't know how to search answer here, I don't know how to use answer if I find something similar, but maybe someone can explain me, what I have wrong in this code and give some advice how to fix it

EDIT

OK, I don't know if I do correct, but this var_dump I use here in my line 94

```
94         $json_result = var_dump($result);
```

and then I get this error

```
bool(false) 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: ' in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php:95 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php(53): BlockIo->_request('get_new_address', Array) #1 /var/www/html/block.php(20): BlockIo->__call('get_new_address', Array) #2 /var/www/html/block.php(20): BlockIo->get_new_address() #3 /var/www/html/deposit.php(76): include('/var/www/html/b...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 95
```

Ok, here is my full php file, maybe someone see mistake other line not the line 95, please help me, I don't know how to fix this error

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29b428d4f224990f865e2a708fd188fd66016766

Comment: can you show the output from "$json_result" with var dump? on line before your error on line 95

Comment: On line 94 your $json_result var is probably not an object. Do a var_dump($json_result) and use json_last_error () do see if there was an error during the last JSON encoding/decoding.

Comment: @Andreas and sorry for stupid question, but where and how I need use var_dump and json_last_error ()?? Really sorry, for question, but I 'm new here and try to learn something

Comment: On line 94 just after your statement do > var_dump($json_result); and edit your question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode( $result, true );` you need to tell the function it is an object

Comment: sorry, but nothing change

Comment: Line 95 should it be => and not -> I believe this should fix your issue

Comment: when I try => then I get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Answer (score 0):

json_decode returns true, false, null, an object or an array depending on the given json input. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

`$json_result->status != 'success'` assumes that on object was returned.

In order to verify this, temporarily change line 95 like this:

```
if ($json_result === true) {
    echo('TRUE');
}
elseif ($json_result === false) {
    echo('FALSE');
}
elseif ($json_result === null) {
    echo('NULL');
}
elseif (is_array($json_result) {
    echo('ARRAY');
    echo($json_result['status'];
}
else {
    echo('EXPECTED OBJECT');
    echo($json_result->status);
}
```

Or check the content of $result in line 92.

Then you see what json you actually have got and what decoded value you get from it.

As the var-dump shows, you seem to get `false`. If `false` is not a valid return value sent by the service, then your curl call is most likely wrong.

Comment: change my line 95 with your example, then I get this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in /var/www/html/lib/block_io.php on line 97`

Comment: ok, I close everything that needed to close, that fix all, but here is another problem, this function was need a generate BTC address, but no function work, but nothing was generate, just executes the function, without result. sorry, for all these stupid things, but I'm really new to PHP and etc.

Comment: when I press generate an address, then I get only success message `do you already have a generated address`, but that's it, but I can't see the result, there are not any generated address

Comment: Put `echo($result);` or `var_dump($result)` (not $json_result) between lines 92 and 93 to see what the curl call returns. Again - if this returns (bool) false, then you have to verify your curl code or check the documentation of the service that you are calling.

Comment: I try both echo and var_dump. I think function work, because I did not get any error, but when I press generate button, function work and page refresh, but my page not show generated address, when I refresh page, then I get notification, that I have already generate address, but I can't see anywhere this address, maybe I need change something from line 95??

Comment: I'm sorry for not helping you any further. Your question is about an error that apparently results from the assumptions that $json_result is an object. But according to your first dump it is a boolean false. I don't even know what generate button or BTC address (Bitcoin?) you are refering to, as the question doesn't explain that. The best advise at this point might be to familiarize yourself with Php and web-technology first.

Comment: I downvoted the question as it is not of general concern. I don't know for what reason it was upvoted by someone else.

Comment: One more thought though: You may call [curl_error($ch)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) before curl_close($ch) to see whether curl_exec returned an error and thus $result === false.

Comment: I try `curl_error($ch)` but didn't get any error, I think everythink work good, but I need change something in this `if ($json_result === true) {
    echo('TRUE');
}
elseif ($json_result === false) {
    echo('FALSE');
}
elseif ($json_result === null) {
    echo('NULL');
}
elseif (is_array($json_result) {
    echo('ARRAY');
    echo($json_result['status'];
}
else {
    echo('EXPECTED OBJECT');
    echo($json_result->status);
}` because everythink works godd, but only problem is that I can't get generate address

Comment: to better understand my problem, here is a screenshot from my problem - the first picture is what they need to look, if everything is ok, then 2 picture is what I see before press generate button, the third picture is what I get when I press generate button https://imgur.com/a/m8MFB

Comment: Ok, I didn't see, but after use `echo($result); or var_dump($result) and curl_error($ch)` I get error `bool(false) NULLbool(false) NULLbool(false) NULL`, but this error I get in dashboard.php which is user profile main page, maybe I can give you my page link and you can register there and see by yourself what is the problem